# how to use JACKSON serializer for domain object used for different services?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have one domain object which is used for 2 different services as below :

```
public class PersonDetails {

    private String personId;    
    private String personMaritalStatus;
    private String personFirstName;
    private String personLastName;

    // setters and getters ...
}
```

and having two different services.

**First One :**

```
public BaseResponse getClient(@QueryParam("id") @DefaultValue("-1") String id) 
{
}
```

this service should return json as below :

```
{ "personId":12, 
  "personMaritalStatus":"married", 
  "personFirstname" :"abc", 
  "personLastname":"pqr" }
```

**Second service :**

```
public BaseResponse getClientName(@QueryParam("id") @DefaultValue("-1") String id) 
{    
}
```

this service should return json as below :

```
{"personFirstname" :"abc"}
```

So if I used `@JsonSerialize(using=PersonDetailsSerializer.class)` over domain object and serializer class will be as below :

```
public class PersonDetailsSerializerextends JsonSerializer<PersonDetails> 
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(PersonDetails personDetails,
                          JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider) 
                              throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("personFirstname", personDetails.getpersonFirstName());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject(); 
    } 
}
```

then it impact response for getPerson service also.

So how can I used service level serialization or is anyother way to handle this, using JACKSON...

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different ObjectMappers one with a MixIn and one without.

```
abstract class PersonNameMixIn {
    @JsonIgnore()
    abstract String getPersonLastName();
    @JsonIgnore()
    abstract String getPersonMaritalStatus();
}

public getClientName() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(PersonDetails.class, PersonNameMixIn.class);
        mapper.writeValue(writer, person);        
}

public getClient() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(writer, person);        
}
```