# How do I serialize an associated object differently using Jackson and annotations?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given the following class hierarchy, I would like Foo to be serialized differently depending on the context it is used in my class hierarchy.

```
public class Foo {
    public String bar;
    public String biz;
}

public class FooContainer {
    public Foo fooA;
    public Foo fooB;
}
```

I would like for the biz attribute to not show up in fooB when I serialize FooContainer.  So the output would look something like the following.

```
{
  "fooA": {"bar": "asdf", "biz": "fdsa"},
  "fooB": {"bar": "qwer"}
}
```

I was going to use something JsonView, but that has to be applied at the mapper layer for all instances of a class, and this is context dependent.

---

On the Jackson user mailing list, Tatu gave the simplest solution (works in 2.0), which I will probably end up using for now.  Awarding the bounty to jlabedo because the answer is an awesome example of how to extend Jackson using custom annotations.

```
public class FooContainer {
    public Foo fooA;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "biz" })
    public Foo fooB;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a combination of a custom serializer with a custom property filter using JsonViews. Here is some code working with Jackson 2.0

Define a custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface FilterUsingView {
    Class<?>[] value();
}
```

Define some Views:

```
// Define your views here
public static class Views {
    public class Public {};
    public class Internal extends Public{};
}
```

Then you can write your entities like this. Note that you may define your own annotation instead of using `@JsonView` :

```
public class Foo {
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public String bar;
    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    public String biz;
}

public class FooContainer {
    public Foo fooA;
    @FilterUsingView(Views.Public.class)
    public Foo fooB;
}
```

Then, here is where the code begins :)
First your custom filter:

```
public static class CustomFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

    private Class<?>[] _nextViews;

    public void setNextViews(Class<?>[] clazz){
        _nextViews = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object bean, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider prov, BeanPropertyWriter writer)
            throws Exception {

        Class<?>[] propViews = writer.getViews();

        if(propViews != null && _nextViews != null){
            for(Class<?> propView : propViews){
                System.out.println(propView.getName());
                for(Class<?> currentView : _nextViews){
                    if(!propView.isAssignableFrom(currentView)){
                        // Do the filtering!
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // The property is not filtered
        writer.serializeAsField(bean, jgen, prov);
    }
}
```

Then a custom `AnnotationIntrospector` that will do two things:

1. Enable your custom filter for any bean... Unless another filter is defined on your class (so you cannot use both of them, if you see what I mean)
2. Enable your CustomSerializer if he found a `@FilterUsingView` annotation.

Here is the code

```
public class CustomAnnotationIntrospector extends AnnotationIntrospector {
    @Override
    public Version version() {
        return DatabindVersion.instance.version();
    }

    @Override
    public Object findFilterId(AnnotatedClass ac) {
      // CustomFilter is used for EVERY Bean, unless another filter is defined
      Object id = super.findFilterId(ac);
      if (id == null) {
        id = "CustomFilter";
      }
      return id;
    }

    @Override
    public Object findSerializer(Annotated am) {
        FilterUsingView annotation = am.getAnnotation(FilterUsingView.class);
        if(annotation == null){
            return null;
        }
        return new CustomSerializer(annotation.value());
    }
}
```

Here is your custom serializer. The only thing it does is passing your annotation's value to your custom filter, then it let the default serializer do the job.

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    private Class<?>[] _activeViews;

    public CustomSerializer(Class<?>[] view){
        _activeViews = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {

        BeanPropertyFilter filter = provider.getConfig().getFilterProvider().findFilter("CustomFilter");
        if(filter instanceof CustomFilter){
            CustomFilter customFilter = (CustomFilter) filter;

            // Tell the filter that we will filter our next property
            customFilter.setNextViews(_activeViews);

            provider.defaultSerializeValue(value, jgen);

            // Property has been filtered and written, do not filter anymore
            customFilter.setNextViews(null);
        }else{
            // You did not define a CustomFilter ? Well this serializer is useless...
            provider.defaultSerializeValue(value, jgen);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally ! Let's put this all together :

```
public class CustomModule extends SimpleModule {

    public CustomModule() {
        super("custom-module", new Version(0, 1, 0, "", "", ""));
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        super.setupModule(context);
        AnnotationIntrospector ai = new CustomAnnotationIntrospector();
        context.appendAnnotationIntrospector(ai);
    }

}



@Test
public void customField() throws Exception {
    FooContainer object = new FooContainer();
    object.fooA = new Foo();
    object.fooA.bar = "asdf";
    object.fooA.biz = "fdsa";
    object.fooB = new Foo();
    object.fooB.bar = "qwer";
    object.fooB.biz = "test";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new CustomModule());

    FilterProvider fp = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("CustomFilter", new CustomFilter());
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    mapper.writer(fp).writeValue(writer, object);

    String expected = "{\"fooA\":{\"bar\":\"asdf\",\"biz\":\"fdsa\"},\"fooB\":{\"bar\":\"qwer\"}}";

    Assert.assertEquals(expected, writer.toString());
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm going to try and integrate your code this morning, and assuming it works I'll award the bounty.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty, and thank you for reporting that @JsonIgnoreProperties can be applied to properties (new since 2.0)! I have some refactoring to do now... However, my solution is still useful if you have a lot of properties to filter.

Comment: One downside I see in your example is that the way you are using _nextViews appears to not be threadsafe.  I'll end up doing something like your example, just with some tweaks.

Comment: @RansomBriggs Hmm, I agree. I had already seen that but didn't have time and forgot. I ended up looking at BeanSerializerModifier.class. I think it can give a thread safe and much simpler implementation. I will look at it tomorrow morning.

Comment: You don't have to, I'm happy with your answer cause it got me to the right place, just noting it if someone else lands here.

Comment: if it not a problem, please, do the refactoring with a multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.SerializerBase;
import org.junit.Test;

class Foo {
    public String bar;
    public String biz;
}

class FooContainer {
    public Foo fooA;
    @JsonSerialize(using = FooCustomSerializer.class)
    public Foo fooB;
}

class FooCustomSerializer extends SerializerBase<Foo> {

    public FooCustomSerializer() {
        super(Foo.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Foo foo, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeObjectField("bar", foo.bar);
        generator.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode getSchema(SerializerProvider arg0, Type arg1) throws JsonMappingException {
        return null;
    }

}

public class JacksonTest {

    @Test
    public void customField() throws Exception {
        FooContainer object = new FooContainer();
        object.fooA = new Foo();
        object.fooA.bar = "asdf";
        object.fooA.biz = "fdsa";
        object.fooB = new Foo();
        object.fooB.bar = "qwer";
        object.fooB.biz = "test";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        mapper.writeValue(writer, object);
        String expected = "{\"fooA\":{\"bar\":\"asdf\",\"biz\":\"fdsa\"},\"fooB\":{\"bar\":\"qwer\"}}";
        assertEquals(expected, writer.toString());
    }

}
```

Using @JsonSerialize(using = FooCustomSerializer.class)
on the  public Foo fooB; field.

http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html

Comment: Trouble with this is that in the real world code there are many more attributes, I want all the rest to map naturally, and just to exclude this one field.  That way I can add an attribute to Foo without having to remember to add the attribute to the serializer as well.

Comment: That constraint was not in your question. Perhaps you can post your real question?

Comment: Perhaps you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616730/how-to-use-jackson-serializer-for-domain-object-used-for-different-services

Answer (score 0):

I would use the google code gson
documentation in here https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
Maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

The annotations are like this:
To expose the field user the `@Expose` annotation
To generate a special name for the field in the parsed json user the `@SerializedName("fieldNameInJSON")` annotation
So your classes would look like this:

```
    public class Foo {
@SerializedName("bar")
    @Expose
        public String bar;
@SerializedName("biz")
    @Expose
        public String biz;
    }

    public class FooContainer {
@SerializedName("fooA")
    @Expose
        public Foo fooA;
@SerializedName("fooB")
    @Expose
        public Foo fooB;
    }
```

To serialize to JSON you will use a code that looks like this:

```
public String convertToJSON(FooContainer fc) {
        if (fc != null) {
            GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
            return gson.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create().toJson(fc);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

It would look the same for Lists for example:

```
public String convertToJSON(List<FooContainer> fcs) {
            if (fcs != null) {
                GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
                return gson.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create().toJson(fcs);
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: Why is this answer down voted? Obviously the question is geared towards Jackson, but IMHO, Gson is a valid alternative, especially for people who have not fully committed their dependencies to Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

The [`@JsonIgnoreProperties`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.12.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) annotation can be used on the `fooB` property in `FooContainer` to ignore the `biz` property only in that specific context.

```java
public class FooContainer {
    public Foo fooA;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "biz" })
    public Foo fooB;
}
```

Note: You mentioned this in the edit you made back in 2012, but I'm writing this up as its own answer since I feel it's the best solution to this specific problem.