# Jackson JSON: dynamically change the view

Tags: java, json, jackson, javassist

Good time!

Say there is such a class:

```
public class Individual {

   @JsonProperty("passport")
   private Passport passport;

   // getters ans setters
}
```

There are two use cases. First, when an income/outgoing json must be in a short format:

```
{
   individual:{
       passport:'123456789'  <-- this is the indentifier
   }
}
```

Second - an extended format:

```
{
   individual:{
       passport:{
             series:'1234',
             number:'1234'
      }
   }
}
```

To handle such cases it is possible to create 2 classes, say,  **IndividualSh** and **IndividualExt** and use annotations `@JsonSerializer` and `@JsonDeserializer` to customize the input/output. I want to try something else to keep the only one **Individual** class, because it has a lot of fields and half of them needs customization. The first idea is to write several serializers/deserializers and a factory, that would mark the problem fields with required serializer/deserializer annotations using, say, the javassist library, but it seems that it is an overhead.

There is a great example by *jlabedo* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676249/how-do-i-serialize-an-associated-object-differently-using-jackson-and-annotation), but I can't realize how to use it in my situation.

Please, suggest, how to do it right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?  What part are you stuck with?  Are you stuck at serializing a Passport two different ways?  Are you stuck at figuring out how to serialize a complex Passport object as a simple JSON string?

Comment: @Programmer Bruce, I'm stuck with serializing nested objects in multiple different ways. Of cource, I can produce several clones of the parent object and annotate them differently, but I don't like this way and try to write a customizing mechanism.

Comment: Of cource, I can produce several clones of the parent object and annotate them differently, but I don't like this way and try to write a customizing mechanism. That's why I use javassist now, but it seems a huge overhead...